# Reorder Grid with Drag and Drop in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

I'm currently building a UWP app which involves a step toward prioritizing the images the user has uploaded. This can contain up to 12 images which will have two rows of six images each.

I've built this grid dynamically creates column- and rowdefinitions based on the number of uploaded images. Each image is loaded inside a , so you have up to twelve of those local blocks inside the grid.

I want to be able to reorder these locals inside the grid by dragging and dropping them like you do in the Start screen on Windows 10. I haven't found any way of doing so thus far, has anyone tried this before? Can't find any information about doing this in a grid, let alone in UWP.

```
<Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Margin="0,200,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   VerticalAlignment="Top" >
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer this.**

[jerrynixonSampleExample explaining Drag and Drop in Gridview](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html)

Comment: After some struggling I managed to swap my Grid for a Gridview, making this work, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but isn't this of any help?

```
GridView.CanReorderItems = true;
```

Comment: That's true for a GridView, however i was using a Grid, which doesn't support CanReorderItems. I managed to swap my Grid for a Gridview though :)